# glTail Boot Errors

Tags: opengl, tail, gltail

For all those who don't know what I am talking about, it's [glTail](http://github.com/Fudge/gltail/tree/master) from [Fudgie](http://www.fudgie.org/).

On my Mac at home, I have never been able to get glTail to work. I have gotten it to work on my work Mac. This is just a last resort, as the past 2 days have been nothing but seems like wasted time.

I have the same libraries installed: Ruby 1.8.6, Gem 1.3.1, net-ssh 1.1.4, Chipmunk 2D, ruby-opengl 0.60.0 and file-tail 1.0.3.

Here is the command that I run to try to start it up:

```
./gl_tail configfile config.yaml
```

It says right off the bat (almost instantaneously):

```
-macbook:bin Garrett$ ./gl_tail configfile config.yaml
./../lib/gl_tail/engine.rb:300: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-03-03) [universal-darwin9.0]

Abort trap
```

If you look at `engine.rb`, it's the first line:

```
    def start
      glutInit() # Line 300
      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE)

      glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
      glutInitWindowSize(@config.screen.window_width, @config.screen.window_height)
      glutCreateWindow('glTail')
```

I have a feeling it's something along the lines of GLUT not being installed properly. I am not expecting too much help, as the code it self has very little documentation as it is. But seeing as it's being killed right away I have a feel maybe it's something that isn't updated all the way, most likely OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is at all helpful to you coming from a linux user, but here goes...
I think you are missing the libglut-headers, indeed. If you are installing through gems, that's the only external thing you would need. On linux, I only have to install the `libglut3-dev` package, then `gem install gltail` it can build `ruby-opengl` with that.

So, try to find the libglut development headers on your platform. Hope that helps!

Comment: It works fine in my Mac at work (this time the gem install gltail, worked) as it always had. But on my Macbook I get the same message, and I can't find any libglut, or glut headers. (I searched for glut.h) What do I need to run to check if I am eligible or to install the libglut3-dev package.

Comment: A simple reinstall fixed it. (Ok, maybe not so simple, heh)